# Floating point matrix stops changing after a few multiplications

Tags: c++, floating-point, matrix-multiplication, pow

I have a `double a[50][50];` 2D array that I initialize with floating point values less than 1. After multiplying the matrix 14-15 times with itself, the matrix remains the same.

To be more specific, I found out `A^k` where `A` is the 2D matrix. The values of the matrix stop changing after 14 multiplications.

How do I prevent this from happening? I want to perform matrix multiplications for large values of `k`,

`1 <= k <= 10^9`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#define ll long long
#define pb push_back
using namespace std;

std::vector<std::vector<double> > A(51, std::vector<double>(51));
void expo(long long t,int n){
    if(t==1)
        return;
    std::vector<std::vector<double> > B(n+1, std::vector<double>(n+1));
    if(t&1){
        for(int x=0;x<n;x++)
            for(int y=0;y<n;y++)
                B[x][y]=A[x][y];
    }
    std::vector<std::vector<double> > C(n+1, std::vector<double>(n+1));
    for(int x=0;x<n;x++)
        for(int y=0;y<n;y++){
            C[x][y]=0;
            for(int z=0;z<n;z++){
                C[x][y]=(C[x][y]+A[x][z]*A[z][y]);
            }
        }
    for(int x=0;x<n;x++)
        for(int y=0;y<n;y++)
            A[x][y]=C[x][y];
    expo(t>>1,n);
    if(t&1){
        for(int x=0;x<n;x++)
            for(int y=0;y<n;y++){
                C[x][y]=0;
                for(int z=0;z<n;z++){
                    C[x][y]=(C[x][y]+A[x][z]*B[z][y]);
                }
            }
        for(int x=0;x<n;x++)
            for(int y=0;y<n;y++)
                A[x][y]=C[x][y];
    }
}
int main(){
    int k;
    cin>>k;
    int ix,iy;
    for(ix=0;ix<50;ix++)
        for(iy=0;iy<50;iy++)
            cin>>A[ix][iy];

    expo(k,50);
    for(int i=0;i<50;i++) 
    {
        for(int j=0;j<50;j++) 
        {
            cout<<A[i][j]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<"\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT:

1. The given matrix is a [Markov Matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_matrix).
2. I have replaced `double a[50][50];` with `std::vector<std::vector<double> > a(50, std::vector<double>(50));` (vector size may vary)

Comment: `double B[n+1][n+1];` This is not legal C++.  Arrays must have their sizes known at compile-time.

Comment: I haven't looked at your code to check it, but if the matrix is supposed to be represent a Markov matrix, then often enough, `A^k->A` especially if you're using finite floating point numbers to represent it.

Comment: As to legal C++, replace those two arrays with this: `std::vector<std::vector<double> > B(n+1, std::vector<double>(n+1));` `std::vector<std::vector<double> > C(n+1, std::vector<double>(n+1));`  Your code will be legal C++ when those changes are made.

Comment: @AviGinsburg - Yes, the matrix that I have is a Markov Matrix. Can you explain why A^k -> A when I am using finite floating point numbers to represent it?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie - I have made the corresponding changes.

Comment: @Rayu You want to look up Steady State Markov Chains. [This](https://fenix.tecnico.ulisboa.pt/downloadFile/3779579688473/6.3.pdf) is an example that should help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll turn my comments into an answer:

[Markov (or stochastic) matrices](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StochasticMatrix.html) can reach a steady state such that no matter what the initial state, the state will be about the same (i.e. steady state) after enough time/iterations. For example (following the slides [here](https://fenix.tecnico.ulisboa.pt/downloadFile/3779579688473/6.3.pdf)):

[image]

After `n` iterations we get that

[image]

Such that any initial state (sum of elements must equal 1) will result in {2/3, 1/3}. When using floating point numbers to represent the matrix values, the change between iteration `n` and `n+1` can often be less that the [ULP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place).